# pts exists but no terminal opening

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, tty

I've installed an ubuntu 16.04 yesterday. Today I installed a xubuntu 16.04 today on previous partitions. But now when I open a new terminal, It sits on pts 2, 6, 7, ... . Because in /dev/pts directory there is 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 numbers. What happened?

Comment: Please describe what you did? Did you make a fresh installation of Xubuntu into a clean partition, or did you keep the files of standard Ubuntu?

Comment: @sudodus I formatted the partitions and then installed Xubuntu

Comment: How do you try to open the terminal windows? Does the corresponding action work in a live system (booted from the Xubuntu install USB drive or DVD disk?

Comment: What exactly is the question? You can use `fuser` to see what process uses a specific pty; for example `sudo fuser -v /dev/pts/0`.

Comment: @AlexP Yes. That was the thing I wanted to learn. So these are applications using each pts 0, 1, 3, 4, 5: `indicator-appli`, `dbus-daemon`, `sh xfce4-session xfwm4 and many others`, `indicator-messa`, `indicator-sound`. And now the question is: WHY?

Comment: @MojtabaShoja: It is likely the those applications have been given those ptys as stdin, stdout, or stderr by their parent. Read the source of the programs which launched those applications and find out why it allocated a pty for them.

Comment: @AlexP Thank you so much. I've learnt something new from you.